# Vue 3 compare references to same objects with proxy wrapper

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I have Parent/child component and bind arrays of object by proxy and without proxy:

```
const selectedTags = ref([]);
const tags = [
    {
        id: 'efrwe',
    },
    {
        id: 'dhjhe23',
    }];

<Child :tags="tags" :selectedTags="selectedTags">
```

In child component i add selected element from 'tags' to 'selectedTags', **its reference to object** from source array!

```
props.selectedTags.push(tags[0]);
```

But then i try compare this reference on same object i return false!

```
console.log(tags[0] == selectedTags[0]); // false
```

You say "okey you try compare proxy object and clear object" but i try comapare with target of proxy and return false again!

```
console.log(tags[0] == selectedTags[0].target); // false
console.log(tags[0] == selectedTags.target[0]); // false
```

i try also with 'value'

```
console.log(tags[0] == selectedTags[0].value); // false
console.log(tags[0] == selectedTags.value[0]); // false
```

how can i compare reference of same object in vue 3 ?

I think you understand that i want do, computed that return non selected items:

```
let nonSelected =  computed(() =>
     props.tags.filter(t => props.selectedTags.every(s => s != t))
);
```

Comment: props are not meant to be mutated. Instead you should emit an event and handle the selection at the  parent component.

Comment: okey i change 'push' to emit('update:selectedTags', selectedTags); And will be check in parent component , nothing change! all next code from question will be work also

Comment: There's no place for trial and error, it's `selectedTags.value[0]`, the problem is that the console is used to debug instead of a debugger, and the value is reduced to a boolean that could be false for multiple reasons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `tags` is regular non-reactive array, and `selectedTags` is deeply reactive, `tags[0]` is regular object, and `selectedTags.value[0]` is reactive object, i.e. `Proxy` instance.

In order to discard a proxy, initial object could be retrieved with `toRaw`:

```
toRaw(tags[0]) === toRaw(selectedTags.value[0]).id
```

`ref` is unnecessary here because it's not reassigned, it could be reactive array.

But the main problem is that the reactivity of `tags` and `selectedTags` is mismatched without a reason. They should either be defined as deeply reactive arrays, e.g. (`readonly` or `reactive`), or both as shallowly reactive arrays (`shallowReactive`, or a combination of `reactive` and `markRaw`).

Generally there wouldn't be such problem because this approach doesn't work well with immutable objects that can be expected to be used in such places. A way to do this is to discard object equality and compare the objects by a property that identifies them, i.e. `id`:

```
tags[0].id === selectedTags[0].id
```

Optional chaining can be used if necessary.

As it was said, it's a bad practice to mutate a prop; this makes data flow more complicated. Instead, a child needs to emit `selectedTags` or a list of `id` to a parent.

Comment: thx. I didn't expect that vue has deep clone object (or 'deep' wrapping).  Is this normal that i use nonreactive and reactive both? i take nonReactive from api like simple json and dont need more that render to template. Or its normal use both with using how you say compare by 'ids' ? Or i should wrap nonreactive to reactive even i dont need reactive ? What is best practice ?

Comment: Objects are not cloned (this would be unwanted) but exactly wrapped in proxies, at least in V3. " take nonReactive from api like simple json" - if you take it asynchronously, you still may want to keep it reactive. Any way, "its normal with using how you say compare by 'ids'" - yes. I always did it like that and never actually paid attention to the problem with reactive/nonreactive mismatch until this question. It's more neat to emit selected ids from a child instead of excessive objects so this way it would end up comparing by ids any way.