# Vue3 prop updates title attribute but not computed prop

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I'm using an external library rendered using Vue3. It has the following component from a third part library [**Edit**: I realize the GitHub repo for that library is out of date, so updating with the actual code in my `node_modules`.]

```
<template>
  <div class="socket" :class="className" :title="socket.name"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, computed } from "vue";
import { kebab } from "./utils";
export default defineComponent({
  props: ["type", "socket"],
  setup(props) {
    const className = computed(() => {
      return kebab([props.type, props.socket.name]);
    });
    return {
      className
    };
  }
});
</script>
```

It renders based on a `Socket` object passed as a prop. When I updated the `name` property of the Socket, I see the title updated accordingly. However, the CSS/class does not update. I've tried `$forceRefresh()` on its parent, but this changes nothing.

**Update**: I was able to move the rendering code to my own repo, so I can now edit this component if needed.

Based on this updated code, it seems the issue is that the class is computed. Is there any way to force this to refresh?

The only time it does is when I reload the code (without refreshing the page) during `vue-cli-service serve`.

For reference, the `| kebab` filter is defined here:

```
Vue.filter('kebab', (str) => {
    const replace = s =>  s.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');

    return Array.isArray(str) ?  str.map(replace) : replace(str);
});
```

Do filtered attributes update differently? I wouldn't think so.

I was also wondering if it could be a reactivity issue, and whether I needed to set the value using `Vue.set`, but as I understand it that's not necessary in Vue3, and it's also not consistent with the title properly updating.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-starter-ina5f9?file=src%2FApp.vue).

Comment: The question says that you use  3 but things that you use are 2 - filter, set. Consider clarifying this. The reactivity in 2 and 3 is different. Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown what is Socket and how socket.name is changed . If it's not reactive, you can't expect a computed to be updated.

Comment: @tony19 thanks for the demo. I think the difference for my setup is that I'm using external JS (not Vue) to update the object. I'm guessing when it's Vue doing the updating it manages the reactivity. I managed a workaround by just not using objects as props.

Answer (score 1):

Computed properties are reactive, however Vue does not expect you to mutate a prop object.

From the documentation:

> Warning
>
> Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so
> if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself
> inside the child component will affect the parent state and Vue is
> unable to warn you against this. As a general rule, you should avoid
> mutating any prop, including objects and arrays as doing so ignores
> one-way data binding and may cause undesired results.

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#one-way-data-flow

I know that this says, that you should not mutate it *in the child*, but the general rule is, that you should not mutate properties at all, but instead create new object with the modified data.

In your case the `computed` function will look for changes in the properties itself, but not the members of the properties, that is why it is not updating.

Comment: Ok, this is helpful to understand (so the old `Vue.set` function and it's Vue3 deprecation only applied to data, and not to props?). However, I cannot create a new object due to the way the underlying library works (or at least this would be cumbersome). Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Ok, I found a very simple workaround: instead of passing an object, pass the individual properties of that object I need. This works well in my limited case, but I could imagine it would be burdensome if there were a lot of properties you needed.

Comment: This rule applies exactly to mutating props in children, and the suggested alternative is 2-way binding. There's no such rule for parents, and not mutating objects won't make data flow simpler. "you should not mutate properties at all, but instead create new object with the modified data" - not really, immutability is not forced in Vue.

Comment: @EstusFlask It not forced, only because it is unreasonably expensive for Vue to prevent such mutations. However, it is discouraged in the article that I have linked.

Comment: @GáborAngyal As I mentioned, there's no such rule, "but the general rule is, that you should not mutate properties at all". The article applies only to mutating props in children (this kind of 2-way binding was bad in AngularJS, and Vue learned the lesson). It shouldn't be extrapolated to any mutations, they are perfectly ok in Vue reactivity and handled correctly. "but not the members of the properties" - that's incorrect, reactivity will handle nested properties, as long as they are reactive. This is apparently not so in the case of the OP `socket`, but this was never confirmed

Comment: @EstusFlask The component has no way knowing wether the object received as property is reactive or not, so it is pragmatic to presume that it is not. If you wish to share a reactive object across components, use a composable that returns a reactive object.

Comment: @GáborAngyal You'll have problems confirming this opinion, that article says about totally different thing, and it's not some common good practice. The component doesn't know, but a dev does. It's pragmatic to design the app the way it may be designed and work correctly without jumping through hoops. As a rule of thumb, all things that can benefit from being reactive like mutable socket.name are made reactive. If they weren't but expected to be, that's a mistake on dev's side

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, but who's mistake would that be? The one who creates the component, or the one who uses it? What if it is part of an npm package? What if the property is sometimes reactive sometimes not? The only way to decide that would be if there would an official convention, that all object and array properties must be reactive. I doubt that that is the case, but if you know otherwise, please point it out in the documentation.

Comment: The conventional behaviour is that all comp properties are reactive, this is how `data` works, this includes V3. Composition api gives fine-grained control over it but it's up to a dev how to use it to not break the convention. So yes, as a rule of thumb, all objects and arrays can be expected to be reactive. Reactivity can be removed for consts, or for performance reasons, but this may cause more problems than it solves, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70919148/3731501 . And reactivity in class instances need extra caution, it's the opposite for them but they aren't first-class citizens in VUe

Comment: Originally this was the OP who provided non-reactive prop from a parent, while reactive one was expected in a child. Then the OP forked a dev and became responsible for both places. So looks like dev's mistake any way.